# Какая техника изучения языка программирования

Tags: книги

Стоит взять одну книгу и зубрить её или лучше выискивать статейки и учить? Как учились Вы?

Comment: От зубрежки толку ноль. Надо читать и пробовать, то что опробовано на практике становится знанием, а не просто информацией.

Answer (score 4):

Читаешь и практикуешься , причём чем больше практикуешься тем лучше .

Answer (score 3):

Техника проста.

- берем побольше книг/статей
- качаем компиляторы/трансляторы
- настраиваем все это
- читаем книгу и пытаемся воспроизвести
- придумываем свою задачу и пытаемся сделать
- PROFIT!

Answer (score 2):

Лично я очень изначально начал с основательного изучения теории, не так о конкретном языке, а, скорее - о программировании в целом.

По книгам я учил только основы языка ( его специфику и т.д. ) Все-таки основные познания, как выяснилось, пришли именно с первых книг( и приходят по сей день ). Основные знания языка - из изучения документации, блогов, форумов и специфических книг, особенно специфических книг( хотел бы заметить что не всегда стоит доверять прочитанной вами информации на "неофициальных" источниках, нередко - качество приведенного кода и примеров в целом, мягко говоря, желает лучшего ). 
Именно специфических, книги типа java, php, javascript, actionscript (подставьте нужное) for dummies ИМХО достаточно - одной.

Т.е. все что от нее требуется - дать понимание конкретного языка, не более.

Не смотря на то что книги это очень и очень важно - практика, все-же, важнее. Что касается меня - я понимал это когда учился, но тем не менее я для себя решил что не начну писать чего-то целостного пока не достигну определенного уровня знаний и понимания. Не могу точно сказать хорошо это или плохо. В любом случае - все что написано в книге вы должны понимать, если вы чего-то не понимаете - это обязательно должно быть исправлено.

Так-же хотел дать совет по поводу грамотного, на мой взгляд, чтения книг о программировании. Все что вам для этого необходимо - ручка и листочек или блокнотик, тетрадь, вообщем что-то эдакое(листочек крайний вариант :)). Ну так вот - вы открыли книгу и читаете себе, рано или поздно вы тупите в одну из глав и ничего не понимаете( или не до конца понимаете, не суть важна ), так вот - просто записываете название главы на листочек и читаете дальше, просто пролистываете эту "капризную" главу на следующую. Если же следующая глава базируеются как-раз на том чего вы не поняли - пропускаем и следующую. Когда доходим до конца книги - начинаем закрывать наши дыры, по своему опыту хочу сказать что практически все книги по программированию я читал именно так и результатом очень и очень доволен. В любом случае - попробуйте, ведь это-же не так сложно в конце концов...

Еще хотел добавить - любому новичку тяжело, программирование "штука" непростая, но подвласна любому человеку обладающему усердностью и элементарной логикой. Не бойтесь того что у вас что-то не будет получатся, пускай даже долго не будет получатся - все-равно рано или поздно вполучиться. Программирование по началу происходит по принципу - мне надо сделать вот это, что мне для этого нужно, потом книга, мануал, форум, гугл и т.д. Вы находите ответ, да поначалу тяжело искать и разбираться, зато потом вы уже знаете как решить эту проблему. Со временем вы учитесь быстро находить ответы на интересующие вас вопросы и быстро применять их на практике, к тому-же - с каждым днем вам будет все проще и проще т.к. в гугл(мануалы, книги и т.д.) вы будете лезть все меньше и меньше.

В любом случае удачи :)

PS:зубрить точно не стоит, вы "переросли" книгу тогда когда все что в ней написаное вы **понимаете** и совсем не обязательно( по началу, во всяком случае, так точно ) все помнить на изусть, опять таки ИМХО.

Answer (score 1):

Когда читаешь книгу по программированию, пытайся продумать и понять все примеры, приводимые в ней. Пробуй воспроизвести эти примеры, не подглядывая в книгу. Выполняй все упражнения и отвечай на все вопросы, если они есть в конце главы.
 Когда дочитаешь, пробуй написать свою программу на интересующую тебя тему. Если что-то забудешь или что-то не будет получаться, подсматривай в книгу. Этим ты закрепишь свои знания. Потом через какое-то время можешь так же проработать другую книгу по этой теме или ту же книгу, и ты уже будешь её читать, лучше всё понимая.

Answer (score 0):

начни со статей
и изучай исходники

Comment: Лучший способ получить помойку в голове.

Comment: Исходники лучше начинать читать как можно позже, когда всё уложится в голове. Даже опытным программистам не очень легко читать чужой код.